# Генерация случайного массива в диапазоне чисел с преобладанием определенных значений

Tags: javascript, массивы, алгоритм, случайные-числа, генерация-случайных-данных

Нужно создавать массив случайно длины, с содержащимися в перемешку числовыми значениями во определенном диапазоне(1-5). При этом надо, что бы определенных значений было больше чем остальных, к примеру цифры 3.

Собираюсь использовать на JavaScript, но мне не важны конкретные примеры, а нужен сам алгоритм - как сделать это оптимальнее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разбиваете участок от 0 до 1 на промежутки. Например, цифра 3 должна быть в 6 раз чаще чем другие. Суммируем вероятности, получается:

```
x + x + 6x + x + x = 1
x = 0.1
```

Значит промежутки выглядят так:

```
[0; 0.1) => 1
[0.1; 0.2) => 2
[0.2, 0.8) => 3
[0.8; 0.9) => 4
[0.9; 1) => 5
```

Дальше генерируем случайное число от 0 до 1, как обычно, и в зависимости от промежутка получаем нужное случайно число.